Migrating AWS S3 sdk V2 to V3 Credentials
I have an app that uploads to AWS. My backend server retrieves cognito credentials (eg Token) and then client app uploads directly into AWS.
Our backend call returns to the user:

Token
IdentityId

After I retrieve the credentials I config the bucket as follows:
  this.setAwsToken(obj.Token);
  this.setAwsIdentityId(obj.IdentityId);
  const credentials = fromCognitoIdentityPool({
    clientConfig: { region: AWSREGION },
    identityPoolId: AWSIDENTITYPOOLID,
    logins: {
      'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': obj.Token
    },
  });

  let bucketName: string = 'uploads;

  this.setBucketName(bucketName);
  this.s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: AWSREGION,
    credentials: credentials,
  });

Then to begin upload we execute below function:
  async setBucketUpload(key: string, body: any, contentType: string): Promise<void> {
const credentials = fromCognitoIdentityPool({
  clientConfig: { region: AWSREGION },
  identityPoolId: AWSIDENTITYPOOLID,
  logins: {
    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': this.getAwsToken()
  },
});

const path = 'client1/' + key;

this.s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: AWSREGION,
  credentials: credentials,
});

const putObjectCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
  Bucket: this.bucketName,
  Key: path,
  Body: body,
  ContentType: contentType,
});

await this.s3Client.send(putObjectCommand);


 }

However we get the following error:

file-upload.page.ts:240 Error during upload NotAuthorizedException:
Invalid login token. Can't pass in a Cognito token.

Not sure what's going wrong here as our old v2 code has no issue uploading as follows. Only thing is missing in above code is IdentityId, but there is no way to set that. Appreciate if anyone can guide me and let me know what I am doing wrong in V3 that could be causing this error?
Working V2
setBucketUpload(key: any, body: any, contentType: string): void {
AWS.config.update({
    region: AWSREGION,
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(
        {
            IdentityPoolId: AWSIDENTITYPOOLID,
            IdentityId: this.getAwsIdentityId(),
            Logins: {
                'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': this.getAwsToken()
            }
        }
    )
});
this.bucket = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({partSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, params: {Bucket: 'uploads/client1', Key: key, Body: body, ContentType: contentType}});


}

